# Flutter Error deploying app from Android Studio to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to launch my flutter app from android studio to my iPhone, and I can't.

when I build my app from Xcode it work, until I stop the process in Xcode and then the app quits on my iPhone.
when I try launch in android studio I get this error:

```
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Error launching app. Try launching from within Xcode via:
    open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version.
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-11-01 13:36:36.578 ios-deploy[40041:293268] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000022: The service is invalid. AMDeviceSecureStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), NULL, &con)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on dabb0ea54361e423bbe5c7824457de5ee2bfa182.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Yochai’s iPhone.
```

I use:
MacBook Pro 2015 13'
iPhone 7
Xcode 12.1
iOS 14.1
Android Studio 4.1
my flutter and dart are up to date
my brew, cocoa pods are up to date

I already tried:
restarting Xcode, android studio, my Mac, my iPhone
tried clean the build, delete the app.

and still get that message every time.
does anyone has a clue about it?

Comment: try changing the iOS deployment target to iOS 9 from iOS 8 in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it fixed,
first upgraded flutter to latest version
then exited Xcode and Android Studio run Flutter Clean
the iOS deployment target was - 12, now its - 9
ran it and it worked.